# É possível realizar um backup de um bd sql server remoto via c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup

Estou utilizando o assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo para realizar o backup de um banco de dados Sql Server em c#. O problema é que da forma que está implementado eu só consigo realizar a ação caso eu esteja rodando a aplicação no mesmo servidor do banco de dados.

Queria saber se é possível realizar o backup remotamente?

Meu exemplo é com base nesse [link do msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms162133.aspx). Segue abaixo o código:

```
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

class A {
   public static void Main() {
      // Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server. 
      Server srv = new Server();
      // Reference the AdventureWorks2012 database. 
      Database db = default(Database);
      db = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks2012"];

      // Store the current recovery model in a variable. 
      int recoverymod;
      recoverymod = (int)db.DatabaseOptions.RecoveryModel;

      // Define a Backup object variable. 
      Backup bk = new Backup();

      // Specify the type of backup, the description, the name, and the database to be backed up. 
      bk.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
      bk.BackupSetDescription = "Full backup of Adventureworks2012";
      bk.BackupSetName = "AdventureWorks2012 Backup";
      bk.Database = "AdventureWorks2012";

      // Declare a BackupDeviceItem by supplying the backup device file name in the constructor, and the type of device is a file. 
      BackupDeviceItem bdi = default(BackupDeviceItem);
      bdi = new BackupDeviceItem("Test_Full_Backup1", DeviceType.File);

      // Add the device to the Backup object. 
      bk.Devices.Add(bdi);
      // Set the Incremental property to False to specify that this is a full database backup. 
      bk.Incremental = false;

      // Set the expiration date. 
      System.DateTime backupdate = new System.DateTime();
      backupdate = new System.DateTime(2006, 10, 5);
      bk.ExpirationDate = backupdate;

      // Specify that the log must be truncated after the backup is complete. 
      bk.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

      // Run SqlBackup to perform the full database backup on the instance of SQL Server. 
      bk.SqlBackup(srv);

      // Inform the user that the backup has been completed. 
      System.Console.WriteLine("Full Backup complete.");

      // Remove the backup device from the Backup object. 
      bk.Devices.Remove(bdi);

      // Make a change to the database, in this case, add a table called test_table. 
      Table t = default(Table);
      t = new Table(db, "test_table");
      Column c = default(Column);
      c = new Column(t, "col", DataType.Int);
      t.Columns.Add(c);
      t.Create();

      // Create another file device for the differential backup and add the Backup object. 
      BackupDeviceItem bdid = default(BackupDeviceItem);
      bdid = new BackupDeviceItem("Test_Differential_Backup1", DeviceType.File);

      // Add the device to the Backup object. 
      bk.Devices.Add(bdid);

      // Set the Incremental property to True for a differential backup. 
      bk.Incremental = true;

      // Run SqlBackup to perform the incremental database backup on the instance of SQL Server. 
      bk.SqlBackup(srv);

      // Inform the user that the differential backup is complete. 
      System.Console.WriteLine("Differential Backup complete.");

      // Remove the device from the Backup object. 
      bk.Devices.Remove(bdid);

      // Delete the AdventureWorks2012 database before restoring it
      // db.Drop();

      // Define a Restore object variable.
      Restore rs = new Restore();

      // Set the NoRecovery property to true, so the transactions are not recovered. 
      rs.NoRecovery = true;

      // Add the device that contains the full database backup to the Restore object. 
      rs.Devices.Add(bdi);

      // Specify the database name. 
      rs.Database = "AdventureWorks2012";

      // Restore the full database backup with no recovery. 
      rs.SqlRestore(srv);

      // Inform the user that the Full Database Restore is complete. 
      Console.WriteLine("Full Database Restore complete.");

      // reacquire a reference to the database
      db = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks2012"];

      // Remove the device from the Restore object.
      rs.Devices.Remove(bdi);

      // Set the NoRecovery property to False. 
      rs.NoRecovery = false;

      // Add the device that contains the differential backup to the Restore object. 
      rs.Devices.Add(bdid);

      // Restore the differential database backup with recovery. 
      rs.SqlRestore(srv);

      // Inform the user that the differential database restore is complete. 
      System.Console.WriteLine("Differential Database Restore complete.");

      // Remove the device. 
      rs.Devices.Remove(bdid);

      // Set the database recovery mode back to its original value.
      db.RecoveryModel = (RecoveryModel)recoverymod;

      // Drop the table that was added. 
      db.Tables["test_table"].Drop();
      db.Alter();

      // Remove the backup files from the hard disk.
      // This location is dependent on the installation of SQL Server
      System.IO.File.Delete("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\Backup\\Test_Full_Backup1");
      System.IO.File.Delete("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\Backup\\Test_Differential_Backup1");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradeço ao @HStackOverflow e ao @Marciano.Andrade pelas soluções alternativas, porém eu consegui resolver com o próprio código que eu tinha postado.

A única parte que eu alterei foi na instância do Server ter adicionado uma conexão. Segue abaixo como ficou.

```
String connectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.0;Initial Catalog=minhaBase;User Id=sa;Password=12344567;";
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
// Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server. 
Server srv = new Server(conn);
```

Answer (score 5):

Se você quer fazer um backup de uma base no MS-Sql Server remotamente, de forma que os arquivos de backup sejam criados no seu computador, sinto muito informar que isso não é possível.
Você pode realizar um backup remoto por script mas os arquivos serão criados apenas localmente (no local da base de dados, ou seja, no servidor).

Existem outras maneiras de se realizar isso, criando scripts que refletem a base de dados que tu está tentando fazer o backup, segue o link do SOEn sobre a mesma questão: [How can I backup a remote SQL Server database to a local drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942207/how-can-i-backup-a-remote-sql-server-database-to-a-local-drive)

@Edit:
Para realizar o backup de uma base SQL remotamente via C# você pode conectar na base e executar um script contendo a rotina de backup que você precisa. Uma forma de gerar esse script é fazendo o backup manualmente, mas antes de clicar no OK da tela de backup, clicar no botão "Script" na barra superior da janela de backup. Isso vai abrir um script com toda a sintaxe necessária para realizar o backup como você quer.
Para ilustrar, aqui vai um exemplo que utilizo:

C#:

```
public static void FazerBackup(string dataBase, string diretorio, string nomeAquivo)
{
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("RealizaBackup", conexao))
    {
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATABASE", dataBase);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIRETORIO", diretorio);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMEARQUIVO", nomeAquivo);
        if (conexao.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            conexao.Open();
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Procedure "RealizaBackup":

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RealizaBackup]
    @database           VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @diretorio          VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @nomeArquivo        VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)
    IF RIGHT(@diretorio,1) != '\'
      SET @diretorio = @diretorio + '\'
    SELECT @sqlCommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + @database + ' TO DISK = ' +
        CHAR(39) + @diretorio + @nomeArquivo + CHAR(39) + 'WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N' + 
        CHAR(39) + @database + '-FULL DATABASE BACKUP' + CHAR(39) + ', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10'
    PRINT @SQLCOMMAND
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sqlCommand 
END
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, porém eu preciso realizar esse backup em uma aplicação c#. De fato queria saber se é possível realizar a ação que hoje eu estou fazendo remotamente.

Comment: Se for apenas criar o backup, posso atualizar a resposta e incluir o script que eu uso para fazer backup da base de dados a partir do C#, mas como eu disse antes esse backup só vai ser criado no servidor do banco de dados.

Comment: Acredito que é interessante, porém foge do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Não foge não, afinal é a implementação do que você quer, realizar o backup de uma base de dados `mssql` pelo C#. Irei atualizar a resposta em breve.

Comment: Quando eu falei foge é que a pergunta se refere a realizar a o backup remotamente. Mas acredito que seria uma opção a mais. Obrigado!

Comment: @psNytrancez Você quer salvar o Backup em uma máquina diferente do servidor? "Fazer backup remotamente" pode ser interpretada de diversas formas, eu entendi que você quer fazer backup de outra máquina, sendo que os arquivos serão salvos no servidor.

Comment: @HStackOverflow Isso mesmo, no início entendi que ele queria criar os arquivos no computador que estivesse rodando o programa, mas pelo jeito ele só quer executar um backup. Para isso atualizei a minha resposta e adicionei um método para realizar tal backup.

Comment: Na verdade eu quero poder realizar o backup e restaurar o backup remotamente, o arquivo e backup pode ficar na máquina do banco mesmo.

Comment: @psNytrancez com a minha resposta já é possível efetuar o backup da base de dados, para efetuar o restore é só trocar o script da procedure de forma que o mesmo reflita o teu script de restore, entendestes? Tem mais alguma em que possa te ajudar? Não deu certo?

Answer (score 3):

Alternativa sem `Procedure`
**Obs:** Mudar `NOMEBD` do comando *SQL* para o nome do banco.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace teste
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string Sqlconnection = @"Server=192.168.0.1;DataBase=master;user id=sa;password=xxx;Connection Timeout=0";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BackupFullDIff();
        }

        public static void BackupFullDIff()
        {
            var localPastaCopia = @"c:\copia";
            var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Sqlconnection);
            sqlConn.Open();

            //BACKUP FULL
            var comandoSql =
                string.Format("BACKUP DATABASE NOMEBD TO DISK='{0}' WITH  INIT ,  " +
                              "NOUNLOAD ,  NAME = N'NOMEBD backup',  " +
                              "NOSKIP ,  STATS = 10,  NOFORMAT ", localPastaCopia + @"\minhaCopiaFull.BAK");
            var sqlComm = new SqlCommand { Connection = sqlConn, CommandText = comandoSql, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //BAKUP DIFERENCIAL
            comandoSql =
            string.Format("BACKUP DATABASE NOMEBD TO DISK='{0}' WITH  INIT ,  " +
                      "NOUNLOAD ,  DIFFERENTIAL ,  NAME = N'NOMEBD backup',  " +
                      "NOSKIP ,  STATS = 10,  NOFORMAT ", localPastaCopia + @"\minhaCopiaDIFF.BAK");
            sqlComm = new SqlCommand { Connection = sqlConn, CommandText = comandoSql, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var localPastaRestauraBd = @"c:\dados_restaura";
            //RESTORE FULL
            comandoSql =
                String.Format("RESTORE DATABASE {0} " +
                "FROM DISK='{1}' " +
                "WITH RECOVERY, " +
                "MOVE 'NOMEBD_data' TO '{2}\\NOMEBD_Data.MDF', " +
                "MOVE 'NOMEBD_log'  TO '{2}\\NOMEBD_Log.LDF'", "NOMEBD", localPastaCopia + @"\minhaCopiaFull.BAK", localPastaRestauraBd);
            sqlComm = new SqlCommand { Connection = sqlConn, CommandText = comandoSql, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //RESTORE FULL e DIFF
            /*
            comandoSql =
                String.Format("RESTORE DATABASE {0} " +
                "FROM DISK='{1}' " +
                "WITH NORECOVERY, " +
                "MOVE 'NOMEBD_data' TO '{2}\\NOMEBD_Data.MDF', " +
                "MOVE 'NOMEBD_log'  TO '{2}\\NOMEBD_Log.LDF'", "NOMEBD", localPastaCopia + @"\minhaCopiaFull.BAK", localPastaRestauraBd);
            sqlComm = new SqlCommand { Connection = sqlConn, CommandText = comandoSql, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            comandoSql =
            String.Format("RESTORE DATABASE {0} " +
            "FROM DISK='{1}' " +
            "WITH RECOVERY, " +
            "MOVE 'NOMEBD_data' TO '{2}\\NOMEBD_Data.MDF', " +
            "MOVE 'NOMEBD_log'  TO '{2}\\NOMEBD_Log.LDF'", "NOMEBD", localPastaCopia + @"\minhaCopiaDiff.BAK", localPastaRestauraBd);
            sqlComm = new SqlCommand { Connection = sqlConn, CommandText = comandoSql, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            */

        }
    }
}
```